# Explanation of the "Proof"

Tags: geometry, proof-explanation, analytic-geometry

I am reading Schwartz's book "A mathematician grappling with his century". On page 54 he writes

> I made an astute discovery of the following theorem: There is a point in the plane through which every real line in the plane passes. The theorem is obviously wrong, but it is quite extraordinary.

He then goes on to give a "proof" which of the above theorem. I am not familiar with the terminology of the proof. So I quote the "proof" below, can someone explain to me the argument?

> Let $D, D'$ be two complex conjugate lines. Their intersection point $O$ is real. If $M, M'$ are distinct complex conjugate numbers on $D, D'$ respectively, then the line $M, M'$ is real. Conversely, every real line cuts $D$ and $D'$ in mutually complex conjugate points. Thus we have an algebraic bijection between the points of two lines $D$ and $D'.$ So by a well-known theorem, it is homographic. But, if there is a homographic correspondence $(M, M')$ between the points of two lines, and if the point of intersection of two lines $O$ correspond to itself, which is the case since it is real, then the line $MM'$ passes through a fixed point. So, all real lines passed through some fixed point.

Now, my questions are as follows?

a) By complex conjugate lines does he mean $D=a+tb$ and $D'=\bar{a}+t\bar{b}$ for some complex numbers $a, b?$

b) What does he mean by $MM'$ is real? Does it mean to parallel to $y$-axis?

c) What is an algebraic bijection? Is it just a one-to-one correspondence?

d) Which well-known theorem is he referring to? And what is a homographic correspondence?

Overall, can someone run through the argument being made here (even though it is obviously false) in a contemporary language which I can understand?

Comment: These definitions aren't in Schwartz's book?

Comment: No. It's his autobiography, and not a mathematics textbook. So, I think he didn't care about giving definitions and stuff. He just mentions it as a life event, but I think I should understand it.

Comment: Then you'll need to get a text on geometry to understand what he's talking about. Does the book give any references?

Comment: No, as I said it is an autobiography. It does not have any references. In the second chapter he is just talking about his school/college days, how they used to learn, discuss mathematics, and so on. So, he mentions one instance where he came up with this theorem, which he later discovered is wrong. Can you tell me the names of geometry books where I can find these terms? A did a quick google search and these terms do not yield anything useful.

Comment: My whole point is that the terms he is using might be "old", and no longer in use, secondly the book has been translated from French so may be it is because of the translation that these terms are not clear. Lastly, in the old days people used "strange terminologies", which might be the case here. The purpose of putting the question here is if someone has read it, and knows what he is talking about, or one has enough knowledge of geometry (and may be old terminology), they might just tell me what he means?

Comment: Further, I do not mean that someone has to explain it to me like a 6 year old child (although I would love that), if anyone knows what the terms like "M'M" is real means, I can make sense of the "proof".

Comment: Any book on projective geometry should help. Are you near a university library? It's very difficult to learn math from an autobiography.

Comment: His book is relatively new (1997) and I think the terms he's using are standard. It'll take too long to explain them here.

Comment: I am not trying to learn math from autobiography. But, while reading the autobiography of one of the finest analyst, I do not want to miss on the mathematics part either. Anyway, I am not near a university library right now, but I can sure go to one tomorrow morning. Meanwhile, I will check in projective geometry books on my shelf.

Comment: What is a "real line" first of all?

Comment: He's talking about lines in complex projective space. The conjugate line is obtained by taking the conjugate of the points on the line. A line is real if it's invariant under conjugation.

Comment: By a homographic map he means a Mobius transformation.